Java code to do Statistics on arrays (using methods), but having error messages
I am pretty new to Java. I'm taking an intro class currently, so I run into many errors along the way with my programs. This code in particular is having issues when I try to use arrays.
The objective is to calculate and output the mean, median, minimum, maximum, range, and skew. We had to save a file in a package called silvestri and then import it into the program to read the numbers and perform all the mathematical functions above.
Lines 57 and 70 has the error "the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int"
Line 35 has the error "this method must return a result of type double" and another error message "the method range(double []) from the type statistics is never used locally
Line 91 has the error: "dead code"
It also outputs the mean twice, but not any of my other sytem.out.println////() statements. What am I doing wrong?
This is my code:

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import silvestri.DataStore;

public class Statistics {
    private final static String TITLE = "Statistics on an Array V1.0";
    private final static String CONTINUE_PROMPT = "Do this again? [y/N] ";
    
    //**********************************************
    // Put as many methods you need here
    private static double mean(double[] x) {
        if (x.length == 0) {
            return Double.NaN;`your text`
        }
        double sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            sum += x[i];
        double mean = sum / x.length;
        System.out.println("The mean is: " + mean);
        return mean;
        
    }

    private static double median (double[] x) {
        double median = 0;
        Arrays.sort(x);
        if (x.length % 2 != 0) {
            median = x[x.length / 2];
            System.out.println("The median is: " + median);
            return median;
        }
        else {
            median = (x[(x.length - 1) / 2] + x[x.length / 2]) / 2.0;
            System.out.println("The median is: " + median);
            return median;
        }
    }
    
    private static double maximum (double[] x) {
        double maximum = x[0];
        double minimum;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x.length[i] > maximum) { 

/*error message: "the type of the expression must be an array type, 
  but it resolved to int" 
*/
                maximum = x[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum is: " + maximum);
        return maximum;
    }
    
    private static double minimum (double[] x) {
        double maximum = x[0];
        double minimum;
            for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (x.length[i] < minimum) { 
/*error message: "the type of the expression must be an array type, 
  but it resolved to int" 
*/
                minimum = x[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The minimum is: " + minimum);
        return minimum;
    }
    
    private static double range (double[] x) {

/* error message: the method range(double []) must return a result of 
   type double
*/
        //initializing maximum and minimum
        double maximum = x[0];
        double minimum = x[0];
        double range = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {

// error message: dead code

                if (x[i] > maximum) {
                    maximum = x[i];
                }
                if (x[i] < minimum) {
                    minimum = x[i];
                }
            System.out.println("The range is: " + range);
            return range = maximum - minimum;
            }
        }
    https://stackoverflow.com/
        public static String skew (double[] x) {
            double sum = 0;
            double mean;
            double median = median(x);
            
            for (double num : x) {
                sum += num;
            }
            mean = sum / x.length;
            
            double difference  = Math.abs(mean-median);
            
                if (mean > median) {
                    return "The data is right skewed";
                }
                // checking if the absolute difference is within 10E-6
                else if (Math.abs(difference) < 10E-6) {
                    return "The data has no skew";
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The data is left skewed");
                }
            }
    
    //**********************************************
    // Start your logic coding in the process method
    private static void process(Scanner input, String args[]) throws Exception {
        double data[] = DataStore.getData();
        double mean = mean(data);
        // write a method called mean that's gonna pass the array doubles & it will return            average
        double ave = mean(data);
    }
    
    //**********************************************
    // Do not change the doThisAgain method
    private static boolean doThisAgain(Scanner input, String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt); 
        String doOver = input.nextLine();
        return doOver.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
    }
    
    //**********************************************
    // Do not change the main method
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Welcome to " + TITLE);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            process(input, args);
        } while (doThisAgain(input, CONTINUE_PROMPT));
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Thank you for using " + TITLE);
    }

}

I tried fixing my array, double and string variables. Some of the code improved, but the lines stated above have issues after I attempted to troubleshoot my code.

Lines 57 and 70 has the error... - You may want to tell what are the lines 35, 57 and 70 in your code where you are seeing errors. (you can edit your post further).

"this method must return a result of type double" -> check your indentation, and where the return statement is; "the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int" -> x.length is an int, what is meant by x.length[i]; "the method ... is never used locally" -> not an error, just a warning that the method is not being used; "dead code" -> see first point

Sorry, I added the comments on the actual code and forgot to add it to my post too. I just added a few // and /* */ comment types right below where i receive the error messages. @–prasad_

"the type of the expression must be an array type, but it resolved to int" means the thing on the left of square brackets [whatever] needs to be an array, and it's an integer. That syntax is for getting the Nth element of an array. You can't get the Nth element of an integer. Doesn't make sense.

@prasad_ Sorry! I added comments on the actual code in eclipse and forgot to add them to my post. I edited my post and put // and /*  */ comment types right under the lines with my error messages.

"must return a result of type double" Seems self-explanatory. Check every "path" through the method. All of them must return a value (and of the right type).

@Michael In the if-statement inside my maximum and minimum methods, i'm trying to compare each nth term within my array to see which one is the smallest term, and largest term. All the numbers within the array are double values with decimal places. Does the x.length method of grabbing the nth term not apply to arrays?

x.length tells you how many element the array has. That's an integer. It's zero, or one, or two, so on... x[n] gets the nth element of an array. x.length[n] - which is what you're doing - doesn't make sense. Maybe it's clearer with brackets: (x.length)[n] - get the integer length of the array, then get the Nth element of that integer (nonsense).

From the code in your question:
if (x.length[i] > maximum) { 

/*error message: "the type of the expression must be an array type, 
  but it resolved to int" 
*/

Computer programming languages contain things called expressions. Expressions return values. The expression x[i] returns the value of the element in array x at index i, for example x[0] returns the first element in array x. The expression x.length returns the number of elements in array x. However there is no x.length[i] expression and that's why you get the error. It should be just x[i].
Also from the code in your question:
if (x[i] < minimum) { 
/*error message: "the type of the expression must be an array type, 
  but it resolved to int" 
*/

Sometimes error messages can be cryptic. The problem here is that you declared variable minimum but did not initialize it. I am referring to this line of your code (that appears two lines above the if statement):
double minimum;

I guess you want that to be:
double minimum = x[0];

Next problem.
private static double range(double[] x) {

/* error message: the method range(double []) must return a result of 
   type double
*/

The return statement is inside the for loop. Note that an array may contain zero elements, in which case the for loop will not be executed which means that the method will not return a value.
The fact that the return statement is inside the for loop is also the cause for the dead code error. In the first iteration of the for loop, the return statement will be executed and therefore the loop will perform exactly one iteration so the i++ will never be executed.
There are other problems but if you compare the below code with yours then I believe you will discover what they are.
(Note that method mean is the only method that checks whether array x contains zero elements. You should really be doing that in all other methods as well. Actually, I would also check whether x is null.)
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import silvestri.DataStore;

public class Statistics {
    private final static String TITLE = "Statistics on an Array V1.0";
    private final static String CONTINUE_PROMPT = "Do this again? [y/N] ";

    private static double mean(double[] x) {
        if (x.length == 0) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            sum += x[i];
        }
        double mean = sum / x.length;
        System.out.println("The mean is: " + mean);
        return mean;
    }

    private static double median(double[] x) {
        double median = 0;
        Arrays.sort(x);
        if (x.length % 2 != 0) {
            median = x[x.length / 2];
            System.out.println("The median is: " + median);
            return median;
        }
        else {
            median = (x[(x.length - 1) / 2] + x[x.length / 2]) / 2.0;
            System.out.println("The median is: " + median);
            return median;
        }
    }

    private static double maximum(double[] x) {
        double maximum = x[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = x[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum is: " + maximum);
        return maximum;
    }

    private static double minimum(double[] x) {
        double minimum = x[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] < minimum) {
                minimum = x[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The minimum is: " + minimum);
        return minimum;
    }

    private static double range(double[] x) {
        // initializing maximum and minimum
        double maximum = x[0];
        double minimum = x[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = x[i];
            }
            if (x[i] < minimum) {
                minimum = x[i];
            }
        }
        double range = maximum - minimum;
        System.out.println("The range is: " + range);
        return range;
    }

    public static String skew(double[] x) {
        double mean = mean(x);
        double median = median(x);
        double difference = Math.abs(mean - median);

        if (mean > median) {
            return "The data is right skewed";
        }
        // checking if the absolute difference is within 10E-6
        else if (Math.abs(difference) < 10E-6) {
            return "The data has no skew";
        }
        else {
            return "The data is left skewed";
        }
    }

    private static void process(Scanner input, String args[]) throws Exception {
        double data[] = DataStore.getData();
        mean(data);
        median(data);
        maximum(data);
        minimum(data);
        range(data);
        System.out.println(skew(data));
    }

    private static boolean doThisAgain(Scanner input, String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String doOver = input.nextLine();
        return doOver.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Welcome to " + TITLE);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            process(input, args);
        } while (doThisAgain(input, CONTINUE_PROMPT));
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Thank you for using " + TITLE);
    }
}

When I ran the above code with the following array
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

I got the following output
The mean is: 4.5
The median is: 4.5
The maximum is: 9.0
The minimum is: 0.0
The range is: 9.0
The mean is: 4.5
The median is: 4.5
The data has no skew
Do this again? [y/N] N
Thank you for using Statistics on an Array V1.0

